# How do I run this command?

Tags: makefile

```
make -C kernel_build_dir M=`pwd` ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<...> modules
```

I am trying to run this command but not sure where I could find "kernel_build_dir" and what is "<...>" ??

What do I enter for <...>?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What software is it you are trying to build? Is there any documentation available on how to build it?

Comment: I am trying to build gator.ko for ARM DS-5 Steamline targeting Android. I got this from the official document and the document does not explain in detail..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do with that command. I'm not sure if it is a custom makefile, or the one you get with the linux sources,or something more exotic; but it looks like you are compiling a Linux kernel. Then, `kernel_build_dir` refers to the directory where your linux sources are stored.

From the `man` of `make` (`man` is your best ally in linux administration. Type `man command` to read a brief on what does `command` do):

> -C dir, --directory=dir
>
> Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing anything
>   else.  If multiple -C options are specified, each is
>   interpreted relative to the
>               previous one: -C / -C etc is equivalent to -C /etc.  This
>   is typically used with recursive invocations of make.

I'm sorry, but i don't know what to enter for "<...>". It looks like some kind of flag you are passing to your build, but i cant tell you anything else if i don't know what do you want to accomplish... Are you getting that command from a tutorial or something? it would help a link.

Anyways, in kernel compilation matters, I found [gentoo distro documentation](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/) very useful and instructive, especially [this part](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=7).